# Jquery show/hide multi-div questions

Tags: jquery, css, html, show-hide

Now if you click link "Button1" or "Button2" it always shows "First Block" with "Second block" or "Third block". But when you click links again Second or Third block will be hidden but First Block is still shown. I need to remove the First block if other blocks are hidden by click. First block should be shown only if one other block is shown.

And link "Show all" should be changed to "Hide all" if all blocks are shown and changed to "Show all" if no blocks are shown. The quantity of blocks will be more than three.

JAVASCRIPT

```
 <script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function(){
var visibleText="Hide all";
var hiddenText="Show all";
$('a#showall').toggle( 
    function() { 
        $('#eventDescriptions>div').slideDown(); 
        $(this).html(visibleText);
    }, 
    function() { 
        $('#eventDescriptions>div').slideUp(); 
        $(this).html(hiddenText);
    } 
);
  $('#eventDescriptions>div').hide();
  $('#eventTitles a').click(function(){
    var target = $(this).attr("rel");
    $(target).slideToggle('slow');
    $('#showalways').show();
  });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
a href="#" id="showall">Show all</a>

<ul id="eventTitles">

    <li><a href="#" id="button1" rel="#divblock1">Button1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="button2" rel="#divblock2">Button2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="eventDescriptions">
  <div id="showalways">First Block</div>
  <div id="divblock1">Second Block</div>
  <div id="divblock2">Third Block</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So in the click event of second and thrid button hide the first block. The naming is funny though: showalways.

Comment: Only hide first block if other blocks aren't shown. If any second and other blocks are shown the first block should be shown.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with these three div's click events alone. You need to add another event that will show first and hide the other two. And then if any event causes either the second or third to display then first is displayed. Perhaps something an event that fires every few seconds to check if both second and third are hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Add hide events to divblock1 and divblock2

where you

check if the other divblock is hidden too and add:

```
 $('#showalways').hide();
```

And to the show events of divblock1 and divblock2:

```
 $('#showalways').show();
```